# how to resolve "segmentation fault" error in "C" for list and file

Tags: c, list, coredump

i have a big problem with my code.

I can't find a solution to the problem. The code works with a "Lista.h" file. the list is created by reading a txt file through the flex analyzer and the bison compiler. Below the codes for the ".c" file and the ".h" library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Lista.h"

double search_CFU(char Cod_M);

Materia *lista;
Materia *ins_M(char cod_m, int anno_c, double CFU){
    Materia *c;
    c = (Materia *)malloc(sizeof(*c));
    c -> cod_m = cod_m;
    c -> anno_c = anno_c;
    c -> CFU = CFU;
}

Carriera *lista1;
Carriera *ins_s(char matr, int anno_c){
    Carriera *s;
    s = (Carriera*)malloc(sizeof(*s));
    s -> matr = matr;
    s -> anno_c = anno_c;
}


double Calc_M(char Cod_M, double voto){
    if(lista -> anno_c == lista1 ->anno_c){
        double num_CFU = search_CFU(Cod_M);
        lista1 -> prodotto = num_CFU * voto;
        lista1 -> CFU += num_CFU;
        lista1 -> num_e+1;
    }
}


double search_CFU(char Cod_M){
    while(lista != NULL){
        if(Cod_M == lista-> cod_m){
            return lista -> CFU;
        }
        else printf("Errore");
    }
}
void print(){
    Carriera *tmp = lista1;
    while(lista1 != NULL){
        printf("%d > %f > %d > %f,2", lista1 -> matr, lista1 -> CFU, lista1 -> num_e, lista1 -> prodotto/ lista1 -> CFU);
        lista = lista -> next;
    }
    lista1 = tmp;   
}
```

library:

```
typedef struct c{ //corsi
    char cod_m;
    int anno_c;
    double CFU;
    struct c *next;
}Materia;

typedef struct s{  //studenti
    char matr;
    int anno_c;
    double CFU;
    double prodotto;
    int num_e;
    struct s *next; 
}Carriera;

Materia *ins_M(char cod_m, int anno_c, double cfu);
Carriera *ins_s(char matr, int anno_c);
double Calc_M(char cod_m, double voto);
```

the output is: segmentation fault. thanks guys

UPDATE:

i have a new error
compilng with "-Wall -Werror"

the error is:

```
Carriera.c: In function ‘ins_M’:
Carriera.c:17:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
   17 | }
      | ^
Carriera.c: In function ‘ins_s’:
Carriera.c:26:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
   26 | }
      | ^
Carriera.c: In function ‘Calc_M’:
Carriera.c:37:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
   37 | }
      | ^
Carriera.c: In function ‘search_CFU’:
Carriera.c:47:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
   47 | }
```

thanks

Comment: `Materia *ins_M(char cod_m, int anno_c, double CFU)` is supposed to return `Materia *`, but doesn't actually return anything. Same for `Carriera *ins_s(...)`, `double Calc_M(...)` and `double search_CFU(char Cod_M)`. Is your compiler not giving you any warnings?

Comment: Please include a small `main()` function that uses this library to trigger the segmentation fault.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: @billLynch the main in a file bison  ".y"

Comment: "i have a new error compilng with "-Wall -Werror"" - that's what `-Werror` does: it converts warnings into errors, so now you're forced to take care of them.

Comment: The fact that you are using the code with a program generated by bison is irrelevant to this question; bison is nowhere involved in the code. So I removed the tag as misleading.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling your code, gcc reports many concerning warnings (which you really should consider as errors):

```
Lista.c:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void
      function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
Lista.c:23:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void
      function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
Lista.c:31:24: warning: expression result unused
      [-Wunused-value]
        lista1 -> num_e+1;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
Lista.c:33:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void
      function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
Lista.c:43:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void
      function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

https://repl.it/repls/SilkySlowAdaware#Lista.c